# Error using multiplication matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot this function in matlab but I get the error: Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Why is this happening?

My code:

```
H_s=2;

f_zero=2;

f=0:0.001:0.01;

S_f=(5*(H_s).^2)/(16*f_zero)*(f/f_zero).^(-5)*exp(-(5/4)*f)   

plot(f,S_f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first terms (`(5*(H_s).^2)/(16*f_zero)*(f/f_zero).^(-5)`) evaluate to a `1x11` matrix, as does the last term (`exp(-(5/4)*f)`). The [matrix multiplication operator `*`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) indeed requires the inner dimensions to match.
But you were probably trying to do [element-wise multiplication `.*`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html):

```
S_f=(5*(H_s).^2)/(16*f_zero)*(f/f_zero).^(-5).*exp(-(5/4)*f)
```